# Selenium + Python Wait for element to contain a randomly generated string of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Noobie here with Selenium and Python.

I am currently trying to figure out a way to find an element by XPATH when any text is generated.

```
randomstring = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='lower-text']/div[2]").text
```

This finds the correct text I am looking for. However, when implemented with a "try, finally", it cannot be located.

```
try: 
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[//div[@class='lower-text']/div[2]" and text() != ""]")
    )
finally:
    randomstring = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='lower-text']/div[2]").text
```

Comment: Why are you using `text() != ""` in your xpath in try block

Comment: Block does not find anything either

Answer (score 0):

`text() != ""` won't work in the xpath. You can fetch the element as you are fetching it by using your original xpath.
If you want to put the code in try catch then you can do it like:

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='lower-text']/div[2]")))
    print(element.text)
except NoSuchElementException:
    # Element not present
```